# Displaying rows in an existing table

Tags: entity-framework

I am using Adam Freeman's book to try to learn ASP.NET C# and have followed his examples. I am now creating a new test 
application with my own database. I have a simple table called: "TestTbl" I want to display information in this table 
in a web form.

I created a class called Item.cs that will be used to represent rows in the "TextTbl" and a EFDbContext.cs file to 
associate the Item.cs Item class with the database. I then created the Repository.cs file for an item repository to 
operate with the EFDbContext.

Finally I created a simple Listing.aspx and associated Listing.aspx.cs file to output and list all of the rows in the 
"TestTbl." When I run the application using the Listing.aspx no rows are displayed the application creates 2 tables in my 
database, 1) "dbo._Migration History" and a table called "dbo.Items" that is empty with no rows.

Using the code below can you tell me what I did wrong. I simply want to list the rows in my "TestTbl." It is obvious 
that I have named something wrong. Can you tell how to fix this.

```
=============================================================
Item.cs
=============================================================

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; 

namespace Test.Models {

    public class Item {
        [Key]
        public int pkTestID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

    }
}


=============================================================
EFDbContext.cs
=============================================================

using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Test.Models.Repository {
    public class EFDbContext : DbContext {
        public DbSet<Item> TestTbl { get; set; }
    }
}


=============================================================
Repository.cs
=============================================================

using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test.Models.Repository {
    public class Repository {
        private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

        public IEnumerable<Item> TestTbl {
            get { return context.TestTbl; }
        }
    }
}

=============================================================
Listing.aspx
=============================================================

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Listing.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test.Pages.Listing" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
         <% foreach (Test.Models.Item prod in GetProducts())
            {
                Response.Write("<div class='item'>");
                Response.Write(prod.Description);
                Response.Write("</div>");
            }%>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


=============================================================
Listing.aspx.cs
=============================================================

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Test.Models;
using Test.Models.Repository;

namespace Test.Pages {
    public partial class Listing : System.Web.UI.Page {
        private Repository repo = new Repository();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        }
        protected IEnumerable<Item> GetProducts() {
            return repo.TestTbl;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You have created empty tables you now have to populate the tables with data yourself.

Comment: The TestTbl has data in it, 3 rows. All I'm trying to do is use the code above to list that data in TestTbl but I've done it wrong, or named something, or referenced something wrong in my classes above.

Comment: You don't get any error message? Have you run it in debug? If the context.TestTbl returns null, there is no data in your table. Check that your code is not using a different connection string or another sql instance (for example sqlexpress instead of your local sql server)